# Multiple Ajax codes only works after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There are two different Ajax codes in my current project. both of them only works after the first page reload. Which means it wont work on page load (example by entering the page URL in browser) first time, I have to refresh the page 1 time and it will work continuously without issues.

it also works if I manually use the URL in the browser address bar and load page.

box ajax codes are different and have complete different functions.
Here is one sample code.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(e){

    load_data(1);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    cache: false;
    function load_data(page, query = '')
    {  
      
      $.ajax({
        url:"lead-fetch.php",
        cache: false,
        method:"POST",
        data:{page:page, query:query},
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('#dynamic_content').html(data);
        }
      });
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.page-link', function(){
     
      var page = $(this).data('page_number');
      var query = $('#search_box').val();
      load_data(page, query);
    });

    $('#search_box').keyup(function(){
      var query = $('#search_box').val();
      load_data(1, query);
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: when you initially open that page, do you see any `XHR` requests being sent in the `Network` tab of the DevTools ?

Comment: @ths,  the lead-fetch.phpis called only when the page manually reloads. it also works if I manualy use the url in the bowser address bar and load page.